# PromQL query to detect the creation of new time series

Tags: prometheus, alert, monitoring, promql

I have a metric with counters type. For a given metric and label combination, I need to detect if a new time series is created for the last one day. If yes, the query should return 1, else return 0 or empty.

I used the below query.

```
count by(label_1, label_2) count_over_time(My_metric{label_1="v1",label_2="v2"}[1d]) > 0
```

This works partly as it detects the new time series but after a day of creation, it still returns 1.

```
My_metric{label_1="v1",label_2="v2"}
```

[Time series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph0z2.png)

```
count by(label_1, label_2) count_over_time(My_metric{label_1="v1",label_2="v2"}[1d]) > 0
```

[Time series with the above the above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k2geg.png)

This timeseries is created around Jan 1, 10AM.
From Jan 1, 10AM - Jan 2 10AM, promQL query should return 1 and rest of time, it should return 0 or empty.  Could someone help on this? Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The following query returns 0 if there were no new time series matching the `My_metric{label_1="v1",label_2="v2"}` [series selector](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/keyConcepts.html#filtering) during the last day. Otherwise it returns 1:

```
count(
  My_metric{label_1="v1",label_2="v2"}
    unless
  (
    My_metric{label_1="v1",label_2="v2"} offset 1d
  )
) >bool 0
```

The query uses the following PromQL features:

- [`offset` modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#offset-modifier)
- [`unless` binary operator](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#logical-set-binary-operators)
- [`bool` modifier](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#comparison-binary-operators) for `>` operator